# Rails 4 - Validate that at least one checkboxe is checked in nested form inside a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, checkbox

I try to create a validation that work in a nested for with a collection of checkboxes.

The collection is inside a each.do loop.

```
<%= simple_form_for @questionnaire do |f| %>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <%= question.name %>
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :answer_ids, Answer.where(question_id: question.id), :id, :content  %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is inside a `Questionnaire` form.

So I try to validate `answer` in the `Questionnaire` model, but I need to do it for each question : each `question` should at least have a checkbox checked.

Any idea would be great! 
Thank you in advance!

EDIT :

The relationship between my 3 models :

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :answers, :through => :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questionnaires
    has_many :answers, through: :questionnaires
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :questionnaires, :through => :answers
end
```

Comment: how you determine that these `answer_ids` are belongs to this `question`, I mean is there any relation between `questionnarie` and `question` or I'm missing something?

Comment: @rony36 Good point, I updated my question so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate `answer_ids` like below

```
validates :answer_ids,  presence: true
```

This line put on your model

I think to help you

Comment: Thanks but it's not what need to be done : this only validate if at least one checkbox is checked, so if for the Question 1 I check one checkbox, it form will be sent, I need to validate that for each Question, at least one checkbox is checked.